# find original coordinate of a point in Cropped image

Tags: python, opencv, roi

I have an image. Using opencv .selectROI to extract the region of interest without any rotation gives me:

```
r=cv2.selectROI(myImage)
ROI=[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
```

In the ROI new image, if given a point (x_new,y_new) how could i find its coordinate (x,y) in the original image?

Comment: Well you should know the x,y pos of where your crop took place in the original image, and you know the x,y point within the cropped image, just add them together.

Comment: You solved my problem. Thank you so much